# Latex error "There's no line here to end" when "\frame{\titlepage}" is used

Tags: latex, beamer

I made a very simple 4-page Presentation in Beamer Class to practice Latex. Everything works just fine with Boadilla Beamer Theme but when I try to use it with a theme that I downloaded, it keeps giving me this error: "There's no line here to end" and when I comment out the title command, it works again. I tried to use \maketitle instead but the problem remained. I read texfaq page of this error but it's mainly caused by white spaces/ line-breaking commands. I have no idea how to print a title page with this theme. Here is my .tex file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen, xspace}
\usetheme{BHT}

\title{abc}
\author{abc}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{abc}

\tableofcontents
\section{abc}
\subsection{abc}
\section{abc}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{abc}

\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\item abc
\item abc
\item abc
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.11]{abc.jpg}
\caption{abc}
\centering
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{abc.jpg}
\caption{abc}
\centering
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Sorry for any unrelated, bad mistakes! It's my second Latex file...

Comment: Is the `BHT` available somewhere for download? Without it, your example compiles fine for me.

Comment: this is the website: https://prof.beuth-hochschule.de/tschirley/latex-werkzeuge/ and you should download the third zip named "bhtBeamer.zip: Vorlage für die beamerclass"

Comment: Without seeing the code of the beamer theme, this is just a guess, but I have seen similar errors when the theme failed to anticipate with an empty field, e.g. no `\institute{...}` or `\subtitle{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme you use fails to check if the fields like `\institute` are actually set before using it. You can work around the bug by using some dummy text like a space `~`.

Unrelated to your problem:

- if your tex distribution is not totally outdated, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that's the default since a couple of years
- beamer does not have a floating mechanism, you don't need `[htbp]` for your figures. Also figures are centred by default in beamer, so you can remove `\centering` as well

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen, xspace}
\usetheme{BHT}

\title{abc}
\author{abc}
\date{\today}
\institute{~}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{abc}

\tableofcontents
\section{abc}
\subsection{abc}
\section{abc}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{abc}

\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\item abc
\item abc
\item abc
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.11]{example-image}
\caption{abc}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{example-image}
\caption{abc}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```